# Whats left of the DART Spacecraft after impact?

Tags: impact, dart

DART impacted Dimorphos with around 6km/sec, which is really fast. I am wondering what is left of the spacecraft? What state is it now probably? Seeking the results of car crashes with 200+ kph when the there is almost nothing left, I think the spacecraft very likely got pulverized!

Comment: I think the keywords to look into are "[hypervelocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervelocity) impact," but that's about as much as I know.

Comment: I believe the most accurate description currently would be “crater”

Comment: 200 km/h is only 55.5 m/s but 6 km/s are 21, 600 km/h. The kinetic energy per kg is 11,666 times bigger. So parts of the spacecraft are not only pulverized but vaporized.

Comment: @Uwe wow that is hefty...